# Create Batch File, Convert to Service, Schedule to Run Daily

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, task, schedule

I need to run an offsite backup .cmd script (batch file) on a Windows 7/8 PC, daily, whether a user is logged on or not. Naturally, Task Scheduler's feature "run if user is logged or not" doesn't work (sarcasm .. thanks M$) because the user has to be logged on at some time then signed out. Moreover, because of the urgency of the task, it *must* run no matter what. For example, if the power goes out and upon restoration the computer reboots, there will be nobody logged on. So, I need to convert the batch file to a service.

I've used NSSM to convert the batch file into a service, but I don't know how to make the service run on a schedule, because, by definition, it's not meant to run that way - I should be using a scheduled task.   So, I'm not sure what to do and all the tutorials I've seen on Google imply that I know VB script and/or C#. Unfortunately, I don't and don't plan to ... I just need a quick fix to work like a Linux cron job.

Thanks!

Comment: Just realized, I can just put some logic into the batch file to loop forever and if time = 1am, then run the backup; otherwise do nothing. Kind of a persistent memory issue .... but I'm open to other answers!

Answer (score 0):

> Task Scheduler's feature "run if user is logged or not" doesn't work (sarcasm .. thanks M$) because the user has to be logged on at some time then signed out.

Are you sure? Because **"run if user is logged or not"** is an option, not a trigger. It should be combined with trigger **"At startup"** to achieve desired result:

[image: Run scheduled task at startup]

If everything else fails, you can use [nncron](http://www.nncron.ru/) to schedule tasks and [install it as service](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/about/install.htm).